# Special characters with KSOAP

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, diacritics

I'm using KSOAP2 to invoke a web service. I am getting a response, but the special characters within that response aren't shown properly.

How can I change that?

EDIT:

Following code is responsible for sending and receiving the data:

```
package org.ksoap2.transport;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.xmlpull.v1.*;

/**
 * A J2SE based HttpTransport layer.
 */
public class HttpTransportSE extends Transport {

    private ServiceConnection connection;

    /**
     * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
     * 
     * @param url
     *            the destination to POST SOAP data
     */
    public HttpTransportSE(String url) {
        super(null, url);
    }

    /**
     * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url and defines a
     * proxy server to use to access it
     * 
     * @param proxy
     *              Proxy information or <code>null</code> for direct access
     * @param url
     *              The destination to POST SOAP data
     */
    public HttpTransportSE(Proxy proxy, String url) {
        super(proxy, url);
    }

    /**
     * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
     * 
     * @param url
     *            the destination to POST SOAP data
     * @param timeout
     *            timeout for connection and Read Timeouts (milliseconds)
     */
    public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout) {
        super(url, timeout);
    }

    /**
     * set the desired soapAction header field
     * 
     * @param soapAction
     *            the desired soapAction
     * @param envelope
     *            the envelope containing the information for the soap call.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws XmlPullParserException
     */
    public void call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

        call(soapAction, envelope, null);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * set the desired soapAction header field
     * 
     * @param soapAction
     *              the desired soapAction
     * @param envelope
     *              the envelope containing the information for the soap call.
     * @param headers
     *              a list of HeaderProperties to be http header properties when establishing the connection
     *                         
     * @return <code>CookieJar</code> with any cookies sent by the server
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws XmlPullParserException
     */
    public List call(String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope, List headers) 
        throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

        if (soapAction == null)
            soapAction = "\"\"";

        byte[] requestData = createRequestData(envelope);

        requestDump = debug ? new String(requestData) : null;
        responseDump = null;

        connection = getServiceConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "kSOAP/2.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + requestData.length);

        // Pass the headers provided by the user along with the call
        if (headers != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                HeaderProperty hp = (HeaderProperty) headers.get(i);
                connection.setRequestProperty(hp.getKey(), hp.getValue());
            }
        }

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();


        OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();

        os.write(requestData, 0, requestData.length);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        requestData = null;
        InputStream is;
        List retHeaders = null;

        try {
            connection.connect();
            is = connection.openInputStream();
            retHeaders = connection.getResponseProperties();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            is = connection.getErrorStream();

            if (is == null) {
                connection.disconnect();
                throw (e);
            }
        }

        if (debug) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            while (true) {
                int rd = is.read(buf, 0, 256);
                if (rd == -1)
                    break;
                bos.write(buf, 0, rd);
            }

            bos.flush();
            buf = bos.toByteArray();
            responseDump = new String(buf);
            is.close();
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        }

        parseResponse(envelope, is);
        return retHeaders;
    }

    public ServiceConnection getConnection() {
        return (ServiceConnectionSE) connection;
    }

    protected ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {
        return new ServiceConnectionSE(proxy, url);
    }

    public String getHost() {

        String retVal = null;

        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getHost();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public int getPort() {

        int retVal = -1;

        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getPort();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public String getPath() {

        String retVal = null;

        try {
            retVal = new URL(url).getPath();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

What lines could I change to enforce a UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: They are German umlauts (ä, ü, ö)

Comment: How are you attempting to show them? In a TextView?

Comment: Have you debugged? If so, what value does your variable show in the debugger? What I'm getting at is, is it your SOAP code or your display code that has the problem?

Comment: The value of the corresponding variable contains dummies where the special character should be (using the debugger), so I'm guessing there's a problem with KSOAP's encoding

Comment: Hmmm, is it encoded as a dummy or does the console font just not know how to render that encoding?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know that; do you know how I could check that?

Comment: Could you try copying the character and pasting it into something like the address bar of your web browser or something?

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant; yes, I did that just now, and the dummy characters are still there.

Comment: Can you paste the KSOAP2 response?

Comment: Well, part of the response looks like this: anyType{cell=Bletterbachschlucht; }
anyType{cell=Stadtf hrung - "G tersloh f r Fr haufsteher- Auf den Spuren G tersloher B cker und Konditoren" ; }
anyType{cell=Michelbach- Loffenau-Bernstein-Michelbach; }. If there are blank spaces, that's where the umlaut is supposed to be. There are also blank spaces in the response-dump, within the xml-tags. Btw., thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: If there are blank spaces in all of your dumps, it's likely the encoding of the XML is different from the text being passed into it.

Comment: Do you know how I could change that, or what the reason for that could be?

Comment: It sounds to me like it's likely a problem with the program that is sending the message and not the client.

Comment: I had the same suspicion, but when I use SOAP UI to display the response, everything looks fine (except the ampersand, which looks ok on the client though).

Comment: @James: Do you know what lines in the above posted code need to be changed to enforce an UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with the specific implementation. It's probably a property in your connection.setRequestProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the encoding wasn't UTF-8, but ISO_8859_1. I converted the ISO_8859_1-encoded inputstream to UTF-8, and now everything is displayed the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if I could help anyone I post my solution.

Similar issue. I searched the server logs and saw my request was ISO-8859-1-encoded, so the server response had this charset too. My solution was override ksoap API. In HttpTransportSE class you put in your question, in the method call, I changed the line:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

I wanted my request was UTF-8-encoded, so I added:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
```

Now, I send a UTF-8 request, and get an UTF-8 response.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar issue when i am trying to send Chinese character to php server and the server get ???,
i found it's a bug of ksoap, please read [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=87) for detail.
this bug is fixed in ksoap2.6.